# Writing a function to a CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I'm following the [CSV documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and I am off on a tangent. How do I write a function into a csv file? I'm trying to write true_or_false(3)'s results to a cell with the following code but it seems like I am missing a bracket, an apostrophe or a parentheses. When I try to write it...I get an "invalid syntax error"

```
import csv
#import module

x = 5

def true_or_false(n):
    return n > x

print true_or_false(3)  

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    #open csv file
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter= ' ',
                            quotechar= '|', quoting =csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                            #quotechar is the character between apostrophes
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    # wrote down this
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam' 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
    # wrote down that
    spamwriter.writerow(true_or_false(3)
    # how to write?
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first, you need to close your paren:

```
spamwriter.writerow(true_or_false(3))
```

And second, you need to put it inside a `list` -- `writerow` expects an iterable:

```
spamwriter.writerow([true_or_false(3)])
```

That should do it.

Comment: That works. Do you know why I need the brackets for the function?

Comment: @RobertBirch he told you - `writerow` expects an iterable.  That means a sequence like a `list`, a `tuple`, or a generator.  A `bool` on the other hand is not an iterable sequence.

Comment: You're making a list of one element -- that's what the brackets are doing. You could, for example, do `spamwriter.writerow([true_or_false(3), true_or_false(4), true_or_false(5)])` and get three values.